# Can a connected regular simple graph have two maximal cliques of different order?

Tags: graph-theory

Can a connected regular simple graph have two maximal cliques of different order?

I know of examples of regular simple graphs having two maximal cliques of different order. But will connectedness change the conclusion? More precisely, I am wondering what is the minimum criteria for a simple graph to have all maximal cliques of same order. Will vertex-transitivity imply that?

Comment: You can see some examples of connected regular simple graphs with maximal cliques of different orders [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeaklyRegularGraph.html) E.g., the "8-cubic graph 2" has two triangles that are maximal cliques but also has edges not in any triangle (and so form a maximal $K_2$).

Comment: @Casteels: Thanks for your example. The 8-cubic graph 2 serves my purpose. However, I wanted to get some condition under which all the maximal cliques will be of same size.